# Profiling a VxWorks system

Tags: vxworks, profiling

We've got  a fairly large application running on VxWorks 5.5.1 that's been developed and modified for around 10 years now. We have some simple home-grown tools to show that we are not using *too* much memory or *too* much processor, but we don't have a good feel for how much headroom we actually have. It's starting to make it difficult to do estimates for future enhancements.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to profile such a system? We've never had much luck getting the Wind River tools to work.

For bonus points: the other complication is that our system has very different behaviors at different times; during start-up it does a lot of stuff, then it sits relatively idle except for brief bursts of activity. If there is a profiler with some programmatic way to have to record state information, I think that'd be very useful too.

FWIW, this is compiled with GCC and written entirely in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done a lot of performance tuning of various kinds of software, including embedded applications. I won't discuss memory profiling - I think that is a different issue.

I can only guess where the "well-known" idea originated that to find performance problems you need to measure performance of various parts. That is a top-down approach, similar to the way governments try to control budget waste, by subdividing. IMHO, it doesn't work very well.
Measurement is OK for seeing if what you did made a difference, but it is poor at telling you what to fix.

What is *good* at telling you what to fix is a bottom-up approach, in which you examine a representative sample of microscopic units of what is being spent, and finding out the full explanation of *why* each one is being spent. This works for a simple statistical reason. If there is a reason why some percent (for example 40%) of samples can be saved, on average 40% of samples will show it, and it doesn't require a huge number of samples. It does require that you examine each sample carefully, and not just sort of aggregate them into bigger bunches.

As a historical example, this is what Harry Truman did at the outbreak of the U.S. involvement in WW II. There was terrific waste in the defense industry. He just got in his car, drove out to the factories, and interviewed the people standing around. Then he went back to the U.S. Senate, explained what the problems were exactly, and got them fixed.

Maybe this is more of an answer than you wanted. Specifically, [this is the method I use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024), and [this is a blow-by-blow example of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773).

ADDED: I guess the idea of finding-by-measuring is simply natural. Around '82 I was working on an embedded system, and I needed to do some performance tuning. The hardware engineer offered to put a timer on the board that I could read (providing from his plenty). IOW he assumed that finding performance problems required timing. I thanked him and declined, because by that time I knew and trusted the random-halt technique (done with an in-circuit-emulator).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Auxiliary Clock available, you could use the SPY utility (configurable via the config.h file) which does give you a very rough approximation of which tasks are using the CPU.

The nice thing about it is that it does not require being attached to the Tornado environment and you can use it from the Kernel shell.

Otherwise, btpierre's suggestion of using taskHookAdd has been used successfully in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on systems that have had luck using locally-built monitoring utilities based on taskSwitchHookAdd and related functions (delete hook, etc).

"Simply" use this to track the number of ticks a given task runs. I realize that this is fairly gross scale information for profiling, but it can be useful depending on your needs.

To see how much cpu% each task is using, calculate the percentage of ticks assigned to each task.

To see how much headroom you have, add a lowest priority "idle" task that just does "while(1){}", and see how much cpu% it is assigned to it. Roughly speaking, that's your headroom.